# Automatic Mount Options enabled, no boot

Tags: boot, mount, fstab, disk

I was trying to mount an external drive that it wasn't recognising for some reason. I then went into disk utility, found a drive I thought was that one, went into the mount options for that drive and changed the option for it to use the automatic mount options. This was not the main drive my OS is on, but probably a remnant of the previous one I had. I am currently in safe mode trying to revert that setting using the root command prompt.

The latest Ubuntu version.

I changed the first one in the Disk Utility menu, under mount options, in what I thought was the ext drive.

So basically what I need is a command to switch off automatic mount options.

```
/# cat /etc/fstab
/etc/fstab: static file system information. 

Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust 
way to name devices
that works even if disks are added or removed. See 
fstab(5).

<file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> 
<pass>

/boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation 
UUID=9762da9f-b9f0-4a9f-9796-ab14d69b3f5f /boot 
ext4 defaults 0 2

/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none swap sw 0 0
```

Comment: Can you add to your question the output of `cat /etc/fstab`?

Comment: Added full fstab content

Comment: Your fstab is wrecked; to provide advice as to how to fix it, information about the UUIDs of your partitions is required. To provide that,  edit your question and provide the output of `sudo blkid`. If your partition setup is complicated, further information may be needed.

Comment: Thank you for your replies chaps, I edited the fstab and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# <file system>                  <mount point> <type> <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root               /     ext4 noatime,errors=remount-ro 0 1
UUID=9762da9f-b9f0-4a9f-9796-ab14d69b3f5f /boot ext4 defaults,noatime  0  2
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1             none  swap    sw  0 0
```

Edited the fstab file to the above and it worked.